# How i add an addListener to GOOGLE MAPS to get MapType V3

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

How i add an addListener to GOOGLE MAPS to get MapType V3

I use

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "maptypechanged", function() {
    var newMapType = map.getCurrentMapType();
    alert(newMapType);
});
```

don't alert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I've understood correctly, I think the event you're looking for is actually called `maptypeid_changed`, and the method of the [`Map`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) class you're looking for is `getMapTypeId`, which returns an instance of [`MapTypeId`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeId):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "maptypeid_changed", function() {
    var newMapType = map.getMapTypeId();
    alert(newMapType);
});
```

Docs for `maptypeid_changed`:

> This event is fired when the mapTypeId property
>   changes.

The `maptypechanged` event, and the `getCurrentMapType` method are both from the version 2 API, which has been officially deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Your event is wrong! It should be like this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "maptypeid_changed", function() {
    var newMapType = map.getMapTypeId();
    alert(newMapType);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a google map expert, but at a first glance, it seems you're not listening to a valid event. Since (at least it seems by reading your code) you're passing a Map object, you should stick on valid Map events. Here (see the events table) there's no 'maptypechanged' event:

http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

Maybe you want the 'maptypeid_changed' event?

Anyway, the first argument of the addEventListener method is the object that fires the event. So as the second argument, you pass an event that will be fired just by THAT object. Though, always find the docs about the object you pass as first arg (in this case Map, but could be for example a Marker object and so on..) and see what are the exact events it fires.